# Convert KeyEventArgs to legible text

Tags: c#, wpf

I am capturing keypresses in my WPF application and get events with a `KeyEventArgs` parameter.

What is the best way to convert that event to legible text taking in consideration special keys and if caps lock or shift is pressed?

A few examples of what I mean.

- Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> prints: `{Enter}`
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> prints: `A`
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> prints: `!` (or what ever the users keyboard layout has there)
- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> prints: `@` (or what ever the users keyboard layout has there)

So far I have this, which doesn't work for upper or lowercase and breaks for a bunch of special keys.

```
void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var k = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    bool isLetterOrDigit = char.IsLetterOrDigit((char)e.KeyCode);
    if (isLetterOrDigit)
    {
        if (e.Shift)
            k.ToUpper();
        else
            k.ToLower();
    }
    else
    {
        k = "{" + k + "}";
    }
    AddKeyChar(k);
}
```

I thought this would be a simple problem, turns out it might not be. ;)

**Edit 1**

Typing the following text: `Test With Text and special chars!@`
currently gets converted to this:

> {LShiftKey}{LShiftKey}{LShiftKey}TEST{Space}{LShiftKey}WITH{Space}{LShiftKey}TEXT{Space}AND{Space}SPECIAL{Space}CHARS{LShiftKey}D1{LControlKey}{RMenu}D2

Comment: It is not a simple problem, use the PreviewTextInput event.

Comment: First of all, `ToUpper` is a pure method and in your case needs to be run like this:  `k = k.ToUpper()`.

Comment: @bashis Heh, I knew that.. coding while tired with too much coffee is always a good idea!